# Parsing XML using Google Apps Script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to ask about the looping not working as per my expectation in Google spreadsheet. When i run with Logger.log it's working, but it show the same value on the range `A2:A20` and `B2:B20`, please advice how to make it work.

This is the XML file that i want to parsing on the Google spreadsheet: http://mong.myee.web.id/RPX/getRevenue.php?track_from=2021-04-01&track_to=2021-05-20

```
function parseXml() {
   
   //Define gsheet output information
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 
   //Set variables to data from server
   var Url = 'http://mong.myee.web.id/RPX/getRevenue.php?track_from=2021-04-01&track_to=2021-05-20';
   var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url).getContentText();
   
   var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
   var root = document.getRootElement();  
   
   var entry = root.getChildren('DATA');
     for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
      var elements1 = entry[i].getChild('AWB').getText();
      var elements2 = entry[i].getChild('SERVICE_TYPE_ID').getText();
      
      sheet.getRange('A2:A20').setValue(root);
      sheet.getRange('B2:B20').setValue(elements2);

      Logger.log(elements1);
      Logger.log(elements2);    
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy fix**

Instead of `getRange('A2:A20')` and `getRange('B2:B20')` use `getRange(i + 2,1)` and `getRange(i + 2,1)` respectively:

```
function parseXml() {
   
   //Define gsheet output information
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 
   //Set variables to data from server
   var Url = 'http://mong.myee.web.id/RPX/getRevenue.php?track_from=2021-04-01&track_to=2021-05-20';
   var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url).getContentText();
   
   var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
   var root = document.getRootElement();  
   
   var entry = root.getChildren('DATA');
     for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
      var elements1 = entry[i].getChild('AWB').getText();
      var elements2 = entry[i].getChild('SERVICE_TYPE_ID').getText();
      
      sheet.getRange(i + 2,1).setValue(elements1);
      sheet.getRange(i + 2,2).setValue(elements2);

      Logger.log(elements1);
      Logger.log(elements2);    
     }
```

Notes:

- Using `setValue` on a range having multiple cells, will add the same value to all the cells, instead add the value to one cell at a time.
- The easy fix and previous note are included to help the OP to understand how `setValue` works.
- In order to write efficiente code, avoid to use SpreadsheetApp methods inside a loop whenever is possible. Instead assign the values to an Array and after the loop finishes add all the values at ones by using `setValues`

Related

- [Long processing time likely due to getValue and cell inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35289183/1595451)
- [How to loop over an array and set/repeat each element X times down the column using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66926007/1595451)

Resources

- [Use batch operations | Best Practices | Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks for your input and suggestion, appreciate it.
Since im new in GAS, need some example for avoid to use SpreadsheetApp methods in loop and  assign the values to an Array and after the loop finishes add all the values at ones by using setValue.

Comment: @Caine0027 I added some links to my answer. I hope that you will find them helpful.